# IOS vs OSX BLE: Instantiating CBCentralManager - coding for iOS

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm learning iOS vs OSX BLE.
I notice that I can't instantiate CBCentralManager in iOS because of:

```
[CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid
Unsupported
```

Versus via OSX because the iOS platform doesn't have the 'App Sandbox' Characteristic where I can set for BLE use.

Here's my iOS Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var bleManager = BLEManager()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("Background")
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

```
class BLEManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    public func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
        case .poweredOn:
            print("power is on")

        case .resetting:
            print("Resetting")
        case .unsupported:
            print("Unsupported")
        case .unauthorized:
            print("UnAuthorized")
        case .unknown:
            print("UnKnown")
        case .poweredOff:
            print("Powered OFF")
        @unknown default:
            print("**** Default ****")
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the required .plist entry:

[image]

I understand that iPhones can be either a BLE center or peripheral.

**Simple Question:** How do I code for a bona fide CBCentralMaster for iOS?

I'm merely taking baby steps here: coding for peripheral detection. 
... then continue from there.

Comment: Are you running on a physical iOS device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running on the simulator (where it is unsupported) instead of on device?

Comment: Via simulator.  I was also doing MacOS which worked.   Thanks for pointing out this out.

Answer (score 0):

See the main [Core Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth) docs:

> Your app will crash if its Info.plist doesn’t include usage description keys for the types of data it needs to access. To access Core Bluetooth APIs on apps linked on or after iOS 13, include the NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key. In iOS 12 and earlier, include NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription to access Bluetooth peripheral data.

Comment: I've included the .plist entry (see revised query above) but I still get the "[CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid"; what would cause this?